# looping through hashMaps in api

Tags: android, json, api, hashmap

this problem is fairly simple but cannot get my head around it.

the following api is to be processed

```
{ "data" : [ { "id" : "102",
        "sector" : "projectSector1",
        "title" : "projectTitle1"
      },
      { "id" : "100",
        "sector" : "projectSector2",
        "title" : "projectTitle2"
      },
      { "id" : "98",
        "sector" : "projectSector3",
        "title" : "projectTitle3"
      }
    ],
  "status" : "success"
}
```

So in my `doInBackground` I am running the following code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            UserFunctions user = new UserFunctions();
            JSob = user.allprojects();
            try {
                JSar = JSob.getJSONArray("data");

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int i=0; i<JSar.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject newobj = JSar.getJSONObject(i);
                    project_title = newobj.getString("title");
                    project_sector = newobj.getString("sector");

                    all_list.put("title", project_title);
                    all_list.put("sector", project_sector);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here I am trying to `HashMap` (the `all_list` is the hashMap) the "sector" and "title" as keys and take in the corresponding values for them in as values. But for some reason I only get projectTitle3 and projectSector3 being accessed two times. Please help !

Comment: i think that by doing this you overwrite the previous values of the keys in the hashmap

Comment: @Pavlos what might be a good solution ?

Comment: Someone answered you below! In your case i would use a database instead! Especially if the json is very long!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows

```
//Create a list of hashmap
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//in doInBackground method
HashMap<String, String> all_list = new HashMap<String, String>();                     
all_list.put("title", project_title);
all_list.put("sector", project_sector);
lst.add(map);
```

Comment: If I use this ArrayList ... how can i create a CustomAdapter for the listView that this activity uses ?

Comment: @user2247689 You can check this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: well this is what i have implemented but I have a checkBox, so a CustomAdapter is needed to enable both the listView click and also the  checkBox click.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are overriding the value with Same key in your HashMap. You should use different key for every loop iteration.

You can concatinate i with key as well.

For Ex :

```
for(int i=0; i<JSar.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject newobj = JSar.getJSONObject(i);
                    project_title = newobj.getString("title");
                    project_sector = newobj.getString("sector");

                    all_list.put("title"+i, project_title);
                    all_list.put("sector"+i, project_sector);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't store to `HashMap` the same keys. Actually you can but only last key will be stored in.  `HashMap` stores only **unique** keys. This is a reason why you got only 2 keys.

To fix it, do:

```
for(int i=0; i<JSar.length(); i++){
            try {
                JSONObject newobj = JSar.getJSONObject(i);
                project_title = newobj.getString("title");
                project_sector = newobj.getString("sector");

                all_list.put("title" + i, project_title);
                all_list.put("sector" + i, project_sector);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```